# Moment.js always gives "a few seconds ago"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this script time.js

```
function changeTime(){
  $('p.text-muted').each(function(index, el) {
    $str = moment($(el).text()).fromNow();
    console.log($str);
    $(el).html('<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  '+$str);
  });
}
changeTime();
setInterval(update, 1000*60);
```

This is one of the places where I'm calling `changeTime()`:

```
<p class="small text-muted" id="t<?php echo($tweet['tid']);?>"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo($tweet['ttime']); ?></p>
```

When `changeTime()` is called for the first time, the values get set properly. But later on, it gives "a few seconds ago".

I understand the problem that on later calls, it becomes a moment('4 days ago'). `fromNow()` becomes "a few seconds ago". So how do I convert this `4 days ago` to actual time and then again call `.fromNow()`? I couldn't find the exact method. Please help.

Thank you :)

Comment: please create a http://liveweave.com/, http://jsfiddle.net/, etc for us to reproduce the behavior

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dvC1DQ4l9a) is the jsfiddle for this question.
The problem is solved... adding it so that it helps others too... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is an error in your pasted code `setInterval(update, 1000*60);` it should be `setInterval(changeTime, 1000*60);`

Secondly please save timestamp in an attribute instead of inside the div

```
<p class="small text-muted" id="t<?php echo($tweet['tid']);?>" data-timestamp="<?php echo($tweet['ttime']); ?>"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo($tweet['ttime']); ?></p>
```

Updated JS code:-

```
function changeTime(){
  $('p.text-muted').each(function(index, el) {
    $str = moment($(el).data('timestamp')).fromNow();
    console.log($str);
    $(el).html('<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  '+$str);
  });
}
changeTime();
setInterval(changeTime, 1000*60);
```

Comment: yaa.. that 'update' was something else.. I pasted it wrongly.. my bad.. Thank you.. :)